# WiFi-Direct using an Access Point

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, internet

I have some doubts about how the Wifi-Direct (P2P) works. I want to connect an android device to a hardware able to use Wifi. I am not sure if I can use Wifi-Direct to connect the android with the hardware using an extenal wifi with internet (Acces Point) or they need to be only connected without any external wifi.

Question: Can I connect the android and the hardware using Wifi-P2P through an external network (Router) or only with a direct connection between them?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you please edit and revise it?

Comment: WiFi direct, pretty much by definition, is intended to remove the need for a dedicated access point/router between the devices. The method you're describing just a typical wireless LAN at present. What's the context of your situation? What problem are you looking to solve?

Answer (score 1):

No.
Wifi direct : direct share data between two devices (pictures, video, music, files), without internet.
Acces point by wifi : acces to internet